# Can I substitute sambucca in my pie crust instead of vodka?

Tags: pie, crust

I accidentally put sambucca in my pie crust instead of vodka. Will it ruin the taste of my pie crust

Comment: Welcome to SA!  I need to hear the story of how you accidentally substituted these.  Just for my own education.

Answer (score 4):

It will add a taste of sambuca (as opposed to vodka's neutral flavour) and lots of sugar, which might affect the texture of the pastry a little. But if the dough came together and felt normal it should still bake decently. The vodka's role in the recipe is to reduce gluten formation, and the alcohol in the sambucca means it will still achieve that purpose.

Whether it will 'ruin' the taste depends on your preferences and what else you are putting in this pie.

Comment: It’s an apple pie. Will that be ok? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ReneeLennon It will be an apple pie with a crust that probably tastes somewhat of sambuca. I, and other users here, are not the ones eating it, so our opinions are not the relevant ones (and StackExchange doesn't take opinion-based questions anyway).

Comment: @ReneeLennon If you found the answer helpful, you can upvote it using the upwards arrow to the left, and if you feel it answered your question you can mark the question as 'answered' using the checkmark (but normally it's good to wait a while before accepting an answer, to give other people time to write).